# Submitting FormData to C#/.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, multipartform-data, form-data

I am running an Angular JS application on top of a C#/.NET legacy framework.

I need to upload & save a file along with some POST data variables, and therefore using the `FormData` api.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('co-lo-import', file);
formData.append('data', someString);
```

Then I make an xhr request like so:

```
$http.post("//some/dot-net/endpoint/Default.aspx",
           formData,
           { headers: { "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data" } 
});
```

On the .NET side, I'm trying to grab these values from the `Request` variable.

```
string someString = Request.Form['data'];

HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = null;

if(Request.Files != null){
    uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
}
```

But these values are always empty. There is never anything in `Request.Form`

I tried `Request.Form.Get("data")` which comes up empty also.

I am seeing the file and data in the request payload:

[image: request body]

How can I grab this data on the back-end using .NET?

Comment: When posting objects created by the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it is important to set the Content-type header to `undefined`.

Comment: @georgeawg this was the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not available in `Request.Form` then try to access the bytes from raw input stream from HTTP request:

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```